# In C, would !~b ever be faster than b == 0xff?

Tags: c, optimization, comparison, bit

From a long time ago I have a memory which has stuck with me that says comparisons against zero are faster than any other value (ahem Z80).

In some C code I'm writing I want to skip values which have all their bits set. Currently the type of these values is `char` but may change. I have two different alternatives to perform the test:

```
if (!~b)
    /* skip */
```

and

```
if (b == 0xff)
    /* skip */
```

Apart from the latter making the assumption that b is an 8bit char whereas the former does not, would the former ever be faster due to the old compare to zero optimization trick, or are the CPUs of today way beyond this kind of thing?

Comment: since you are not writing assembly code the question cannot be answered since the optimization takes care of such details.

Comment: as usual, it depends.  but, it's pretty safe to say that whatever compiler you're using will be smart enough to create the fastest code in either case.

Comment: As an ex-Z80 programmer I think you are wrong in your initial assumption.

Comment: The assembler generated by gcc with O0 is identical.

Comment: @Neil, TBH I'm unsure of the origins of this memory, but it's persisted in my mind. My first computer was an Amstrad CPC 464 (Z80 CPU) and perhaps it was true for Locomotive BASIC.

Comment: The 6502 had a zero-flag that was set by simply loading the value into the accumulator without the need of an additional compare. The Z80 had a zero-flag, too. (http://z80-heaven.wikidot.com/flags-and-bit-level-instructions) Don't remember if it is set on load, but it will be set with a simple OR A instead of a compare (further down the page).

Comment: @Secure: that rings a bell, that must be where I got it from, thanks.

Comment: 2B | !2B, that is the question.

Comment: (!~b) works for x of any size and signed-ness, while (b == 0xff) only works for bytes and signed-ness can be an issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it is faster, the compiler will substitute it for you.

In general, you can't write C better than the compiler can optimize it. And it is architecture specific anyway.

In short, **don't worry about it** unless that sub-micro-nano-second is ultra important

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure that even if it was faster, the rest of the code would reduce the speed increase to zero. I do know to not worry about micro-optimizations, but just can't help myself sometimes ;-)

Answer (score 7):

From what I recall in my architecture classes, I believe they should be equally fast. Both have 2 instructions.

First example
    1. Negate b into a temp register
    2. Compare temp register equal 0

Second example
    1. Subtract 0xff from b into a temp register
    2. Compare temp register equal to 0

These are basically identical, and besides, even if your particular architecture requires more  or less than this, is it really worth the fraction of a nanosecond? Several minutes have been spent just answering this question.

Comment: +1 for -- "Several minutes have been spent just answering this question."

Answer (score 3):

I would say it's not so much the that *CPUs* are beyond these kind of tricks as it is the *compilers*.

The CPUs of today *are*, however, beyond simple tricks which pull an extra clock-tick or two of speed.  Even if you do this 100,000 times a second, we are still only talking about an increase in speed of 0.00003 seconds on a single-core 3Ghz computer - it is simply not worth your time to worry about things like this.

Answer (score 2):

Go with the one that will be easier for the person who is maintaining your code to understand. If you have a successful product, most of the expense in software is in maintenance. If you write cryptic code you add to that expense. If you don't have a successful product, it doesn't matter because no one will have to maintain it. I have been in situations where I had to save every byte I could, and had to resort to tricks like the one you gave, but I only do it as the very very very last resort.